# Virtuemart database connection in Joomla 1.1

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, virtuemart

I'm modifying the Product Form to add in a field that allows a tagline for products. In the database, I've created a new field in the jos_vm_product table and added an entry in the $fields array in the ps.product.php file.

In my product.product_form.php file I've used this code to insert the tagline into the database:

```
<textarea class="inputbox" name="product_tagline" id="product_tagline" cols="35" rows="4" ><?php echo $db->sf("product_tagline"); ?></textarea>
```

And the problem that is occurring is the db field is not being populated nor are there any error messages.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to modify the model.

Model for the product table is located in admin section

> /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/ps_product.php

Modify two functions add() and update(). Make sure the *product_tagline* is included in the SQL statement.